# FLEX: make element expand over sister elements

Tags: apache-flex

My application consists of a Panel with 3 VBox's inside it. the left most VBox contains a TileList. The TileList has many tiles and scrolls down very far so I want to give them an option to expand it. I want the Tilelist to stretch to the right covering the other 2 VBox's. Since it is on the left it is first in the MXML which I believe makes it lower on the display list.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks!!

Comment: So I made the Panel layout absolute and used a <Resize> to make it expand. Seems work good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the Panel to layout Absolute, then put the TileList VBox last in the MXML so it would be highest on the display list. Then I used a < Resize /> to make it expand over its sister elements.